# Android Preference API styling

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I wanted to follow the good paths and try to use [Android's Preference API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).
From the documentation:

> If you want to provide settings for your app, you should use Android's Preference APIs to build an interface that's consistent with the user experience in other Android apps (including the system settings).

I tried to make a simple proof-of-concept XML file for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Profile information"
        android:key="pref_key_profile_settings">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="Username"
            android:key="pref_key_username"
            android:defaultValue="John Doe"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="Phone number"
            android:key="pref_key_phone_number"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="Email"
            android:key="pref_key_email"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Account"
        android:key="pref_key_account_settings">

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_key_credit"
            android:title="Remaining calling credits"
            android:summary="Calling credits are consumed by the second on a per-call basis. Rates vary according to destination. During testing phases, call credits are offered and may not be topped up."/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Text-Call"
        android:key="pref_key_text_call_settings">
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Application"
        android:key="pref_key_application_settings">
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The end result is pretty disappointing. It renders more or less the same as system Settings in **Nexus 5**, while on **LG L Fino** or **Samsung Galaxy S4** it is completely different than native Android Settings.

Am I missing something (a style?) or does the statement from the documentation about being inline with other apps on the device is nothing more than a wish that has never become a true?

[image: Settings demo]
[image: Native Settings Fino]
[image: Native Settings S4]

And here it how it looks like on Samsung S4: the demo and Gmail settings.
The checkboxes are not the same, the fonts and colours as well.
Does it mean every app settings UI look and feel is different?
Where is the consistency?

[image: Samsung S4 Demo Settings]
[image: Samsung S4 Gmail Settings]

Comment: try to remove from settings that comic font . Your page does not look bad, Maybe try another background and add icons in front of  username/ email etc

Comment: The comic font comes from LG L Fino. This is the default font on this device. I'm using PreferenceFragment not the custom layout. And it doesn't render well. Everything is so grey and sad. I would like to avoid styling from scratch. Anyway I cannot probably style it to match LG L Fino and S4 at the same time. And the documentation says it should happen out of the box.

Comment: Here <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   can you add background - white ? add background white evrywere

Comment: Anyway , supposing that you do this for a client , speak with him , and if your app has a design identy my oppinion is to do it using the custom design . In Facebook settings for example - it is simple and  it does not use preferencesscreen .

Comment: I'm afraid you are right and I would have to go for custom design. And then I would throw away the whole Preferences API as it introduces nothing than an additional interface that I would have to adapt to.